# Want Page Title to show on menu, but not on page

Tags: pages

I have set up a static home page.  I would like the title, Home, to show on the menu, but not on the page.  Can you tell me how to accomplish this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A possible quick fix is to duplicate your `page.php` or `index.php` template file, rename it `front-page.php`, then open it and delete `the_title();` and any html tags around it, like `<h1>` `</h1>` or whatever the title is wrapped in.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to Milo's suggestion is to modify `page.php` to wrap `the_title()` in a conditional. e.g. replace this:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

...with this:

```
<?php if ( ! is_front_page() ) { ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Chip & Milo's answers would work, or, if you have [body_classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) enabled (so that unique classes are added to each page's body class) you could just add this to your CSS:

```
.home h1 { display: none; }
```

Depending on the theme that h1 will have a unique style applied to it as well, like:

```
.home h1.page-title {display: none; }
```

which would be even better, as then you wouldn't accidentally hide any other  tags on that page.

G'luck.